# Way to post from foursquare to facebook group?

Tags: ios, foursquare, facebook-social-plugins

Either programmatically , or "right out of the box" (that I'm not seeing), is there a way to 
make posts from foursquare go directly to a facebook group (assuming I own the group).

Answer (score 0):

Currently, the only [broadcast options](https://developer.foursquare.com/docs/checkins/add) Foursquare offers is to the user's Facebook or Twitter accounts, not for groups owned by the Facebook user.